# dedicated frame for mu4e

Tags: frames, mu4e

I'd like to run mu4e in a dedicated frame but on the same emacs server. The following function gets me almost there:

```
(defun malb/mail ()
  (interactive)
 (select-frame (make-frame-command))
 (toggle-frame-maximized) ;; HACK, I usually run maximised
 (sleep-for 0.1) ;; this is a HACK
 (set-frame-size (selected-frame) 200 64)
 (mu4e))
```

That is, it creates a new frame in which mu4e is started. However, that frame is just like any other emacs frame and might visit any buffer when I close a buffer created by mu4e. How can I dedicate this frame to mu4e and mu4e only?

Comment: The following link to a thread -- entitled **How to intercept a file before it opens and decide which frame** -- contains an example that works with non-file-visiting buffers:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame  Consider incorporating `frame-bufs` to associate the buffer with the frame so that you can have frame-local buffer associations:  https://github.com/alpaker/Frame-Bufs  If you like `frame-bufs`, just add `(frame-bufs--add-buffer buf frame)` at the appropriate sections of the above-mentioned example.

Comment: A new feature (21415) was implemented about a month ago by Anders and Martin that permits Emacs to create a frame with precise pixel specifications, if that is something that interests you.  [In other words, the frame is absolutely perfect (at whatever pixel dimension a user wants) from the time it is created -- no resizing, no waiting, no moving, etc.]  It is available in Emacs 25 and also the master branch.  Here is the feature thread:  https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21415

Comment: You'll need to use [dedicated windows](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html) within the frame.

Comment: If you need assistance with a custom kill-buffer function that works with the concepts mentioned in the first comment above, then let me know.  I use it to check to see if there is an existing buffer associated with the open frame (if so, then default kill-buffer behavior) -- if there is more than one frame and the buffer being killed is the last associated with the open frame, then delete the open frame.  [I have also configured tabbar to work with the frame-bufs, if that is something that interests you -- i.e., dynamic groupings of tabs based on frame-bufs associated buffers.]

Comment: I think `set-window-dedicated-p` won't work, as I'd want any mu4e window to be permissible, but nothing else, I'd need something which takes a list of elisp function to decide.

Comment: To give more details (should I update the question?), I think the issue arises from [helm-mu](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-mu). When I open a message from it and then close the message, I'm back to some more or less random buffer. I think this is because it interacts not too well with `mu4e~view-quit-buffer`.

Comment: The behavior you describe in the question is the default behavior of Emacs.  Buffers are not associated/dedicated to any particular frame.  In addition to the master buffer-list, each frame has its own individual buffer-list, but that individual frame buffer-list is by no means a reliable method to ensure specific buffers remain associated -- i.e., these buffer-lists change all the time.  If you want attention, editing the question with more details will cause it to rise to the top of the active list.  If you want a specific person, use the `@` symbol in a comment such as:  @MartinR.Albrecht